# Checking balanced parentheses in a string with stacks in c

Tags: c, stack

I am trying to write a program where i implement stacks with arrays and use them to check if a given string has balanced parentheses.

For ex. if inputted '(()){}[()]' ,program would output 'Balanced', otherwise if inputted '({})[' the program would output 'Not balanced'.

This part is the array implementation of the stack.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

#define MAX 50

int stack[MAX];
int top=-1;

void push(char val){
    if(top==MAX-1){
        printf("stack is already full,error\n");
    
    }else{
        top++;
        stack[top]=val;
    }
}

char pop(){
    if(top==-1){
        printf("not enough elements,error\n");
        exit(1);
    }else{
        top--;
        return stack[top];
    }
}
```

This part is the implementation of a common method to solve the problem.

```
int isMatching(char c1, char c2){ 
    if(c1=='{' && c2=='}') 
        return 1; 
        
    else if(c1 =='(' && c2==')') 
        return 1; 
        
    else if(c1=='[' && c2==']') 
        return 1; 
    
    return 0; 
} 

int isBalanced(char str[]){
    int i=0;
    
    while(str[i]!='\0'){
        if(str[i]=='{' || str[i]=='[' || str[i]=='('){
            push(str[i]);
        }
        if(str[i]==')' || str[i] == ']' || str[i]=='}'){ 
            if(stack==NULL){
                return 0; 
            }
            if(!isMatching(pop(), str[i])){
                return 0;
            }
        } 
        i++; 

    }
    
    if(stack==NULL){
        return 1; // balanced parenthesis
    }else{
        return 0; // not balanced parenthesis
    }
}
```

And this is the main function where the user inputs a string and it's tested if it's 'Balanced' or not.

```
int main(){
    char str[MAX];
    int flag;
    printf("Enter the string with the brackets and etc.\n");
    fgets(str, sizeof(str),stdin); 
    flag=isBalanced(str);
    if(flag==1){
        printf("Balanced\n");
    }
    else{
        printf("Not balanced\n"); 
    }
    
    return 0;
}
```

When i input a very simple example, i get a wrong answer, for instance

```
Enter the string with the brackets and etc.
()
Not balanced
```

This is supposed to output 'Balanced' instead.I don't understand how this could have occured.

Comment: If you call pop when top==0 then you will return stack[-1] - This looks wrong to me.

Comment: ... and `if(stack==NULL)` too...

Comment: @jmq why is it wrong?

Comment: @user5329483 should i use a different condition for checking if the stack is empty?

Comment: stack[-1] is wrong because using a negative array index will result in undefined behavior.  The valid indexes for your array are 0-49.

Comment: `stack[top]` would be the first candidate to be popped. When starting You initialized `top` with -1. This is an illegal index and a **great** indicator for "nothing to pop, because stack is empty". `if (top<0) then empty` brings the correct result right at the beginning.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

in pop(), you are decrementing before returning the top element.  Change:

```
    top--;
    return stack[top];
```

to

```
    return stack[top--];
```

Also, in isBalanced(), stack is NEVER null, so delete:

```
        if(stack==NULL){
            return 0; 
        }
```

and change the balanced check to look for the empty stack from:

```
if(stack==NULL){
    return 1; // balanced parenthesis
}else{
    return 0; // not balanced parenthesis
}
```

To:

```
if(top==-1){
    return 1; // balanced parenthesis
}else{
    return 0; // not balanced parenthesis
}
```

After making these changes, your code appeared to work on my box.  This isn't quite how I'd have coded it, but this is the minimal set of changes to make it work.

Answer (score 0):

`if (stack==NULL)` is the problem here, stack will never be NULL.
You need to check if there are still elements in your stack, by verifying that `top > 0`

Answer (score 0):

You implemented the push/pop combo wrong. If you push one character `top` becomes 0. If you popping it immediately it finally executes `top--; return stack[top]`, which evaluates to stack[-1].

Try this push/pop:

```
int top=-1; //idx to be popped next; <0 -> invalid

void push(char val)
{
    if(top==MAX-2)
        printf("stack is already full,error\n");
    else
        stack[++top]=val;
}

char pop()
{
    if(top<0) return '\0'; //no abort, just return invalid char
    return stack[top--];
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The answer to your question has already been satisfactorily answered, but as a suggestion for a different approach, consider the following.

Since there are only a very small number of common enclosures used within C source code you can easily track pairs of them using an increment-decrement counter.  The following uses a struct, `typedef`ed to `balanced_s` which is encapsulated into a function to simplify the evaluation.  Following is a sample implementation:

```
typedef struct {
    int paren;
    int curly;
    int square;
    bool bBal
}balanced_s;

balanced_s * balanced_enclosures(const char *source);

int main(void)
{
    char in[5000] = {0};//you could improve this by reading file size 
                        //first then creating array sized accordingly
    
    FILE *fp = fopen("C:\\play\\source.c", "r");//using copy of this source to test
    if(fp)
    {
        size_t bytes = fread(in, 1, sizeof(in), fp);
    }
    
    balanced_s * b = balanced_enclosures(in);
    
    bool balanced = b->bBal;//If not true, inspect the rest of the
                            //members to see where the imbalance has occurred.
    
    free(b);
    
    return 0;
}

balanced_s * balanced_enclosures(const char *source)
{
    balanced_s *pBal = malloc(sizeof(*pBal));
    memset(pBal, 0, sizeof(*pBal));
    
    while(*source)
    {
        switch(*source) {
            case '(':
                pBal->paren++;
                break;
            case ')':
                pBal->paren--;
                break;
            case '{':
                pBal->curly++;
                break;
            case '}':
                pBal->curly--;
                break;
            case '[':
                pBal->square++;
                break;
            case ']':
                pBal->square--;
                break;
        }
        source++;
        pBal->bBal = (!pBal->paren && !pBal->curly && !pBal->square);
    }
    return pBal;
}
```