# checking balance parenthesis of an expression using stack in c

Tags: c, algorithm, validation, data-structures, stack

**Application of stack**

So recently came across this question where an expression is given with some parenthesis and we are told to check whether the expression is balanced or not.

This is what i have done till now, but i cant seem to pop the elements from the stack. When i pop it in the else part of the function i can seem to properly compare it.

How can i make my code work, and what is the reason for the simple comparison condition not to work?

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdbool.h>

char stack[30];
int top = 0;

bool spec = 0;
void push(char x){
    if (top == 30)
        printf("Full\n");
    else{
        stack[top] = x;
        top++;
    }
}

void pop(char x){
    if (top == 0)
        spec = 1;
    else{
        if (x == stack[top-1])
            top--;
    }
}

int main()
{
    char temp[30];
    scanf("%s", temp);

    for (int i = 0; temp[i] != '\0'; i++)
    {
        if (temp[i] == '(' || temp[i] == '{' || temp[i] == '[')
            push(temp[i]);
        else if (temp[i] == ')' || temp[i] == '}' || temp[i] == ']')
            pop(temp[i]);
    }

    for (int i = 0; i < top; i++){
        printf("%c", stack[i]);
    }
    if (top != 0)
        printf("Unbalanced");
    else
        printf("Balanced");
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: In the condition `if (x == stack[top-1])`, what happens if the value of `stack[top - 1]` is equal to `0`? That might be a valid value on the stack, but it will be considered "false" and therefore not update `top`.

Comment: There are many such questions here on StackOverflow. Perhaps https://stackoverflow.com/a/64975277/56778 or one of the others would be helpful.

Answer (score 0):

When you read the closing parenthesis or braces you should not only pop the stack, but also compare the popped value to see if it's a corresponding opening parenthesis or brace.

So you first need to modify the `pop` function to *return* the popped value:

```
char pop(void)
{
    if (top > 0)
    {
        return stack[--top];
    }
    else
    {
        return 0;  // Error: Stack underflow
    }
}
```

Then you need to get the popped character and check it:

```
if (temp[i] == '(' || temp[i] == '{' || temp[i] == '[')
{
    push(temp[i]);
}
else if (temp[i] == ')' || temp[i] == '}' || temp[i] == ']')
{
    char opening = pop();  // Pop and get value

    if ((temp[i] == ')' && opening != '(') ||
        (temp[i] == '}' && opening != '{') ||
        (temp[i] == ']' && opening != '['))
    {
        // TODO: Not matching, handle it in some appropriate way
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Once one gets going, it's hard to stop with these things. Intending to "lightly touch" your code, this is what resulted. I hope the comments make clear what it is doing... Primarily, for any of the 3 types of "open", this "pushes" its mate onto the stack. Then when a "close" is encountered, it is passed to `popExpect()` for validation against what's on the top of the stack (if anything). That function returns a boolean yes/no to continue.

Anyway...

```
#include <stdio.h>

#define STACKSIZE 30 // One "magic number" in this source

char stack[ STACKSIZE ]; // Global, but let's go with it
int top = 0;

void push( char x ) { // little change here
    if( top == STACKSIZE )
        puts( "Stack Full");
    else
        stack[ top++ ] = x;
}

bool popExpect( char c ) { // compare expected char on top with passed char
    return top && c == stack[ --top ];
}

// function "broken out" for repeated tests
bool chk( const char *str ) {
    char *cp, pairs[] = "(){}[]"; // three important pairs

    bool isGood = true; // optimism

    // while good and not finished string
    for( int i = 0; isGood && str[ i ]; i++ )

        // is this char one of the "special" ones?
        if( ( cp = strchr( pairs, str[ i ] ) ) != NULL ) {

            // which "special" char is it?
            int off = cp - pairs;

            // because "paired" 0,2,4 are open, 1,3,5 are close
            if( off%2 == 0 ) // opening
                push( cp[1] ); // push the close that matches this open
            else // special closing
                isGood = popExpect( str[ i ] ); // does this close match?
        }

    // all good and nothing left on the stack
    return isGood && top == 0;
}

int main() {
    const char *s1 = "(foobar)({}){bar}[[[(foo)]]]"; // balanced
    const char *s2 = "(foobar)({}){ { bar}[[[(foo)]]]"; // unbalanced open
    const char *s3 = "(foobar)({}){ ] bar}[[[(foo)]]]"; // unbalanced close

    puts( chk( s1 ) ? "Balanced" : "Unbalanced" );
    puts( chk( s2 ) ? "Balanced" : "Unbalanced" );
    puts( chk( s3 ) ? "Balanced" : "Unbalanced" );

    return 0;
}
```